# How to modify an R package to create a new package for Reweighted Kernel Density Estimation?

Tags: r, statistics

I am working on "Reweighted Kernel Density Estimation".
I couldn't find any package in R for "weighted bivariate density estimation.
That's why I am going to modify availabe univariate packages. But I don't know how to access to source code for those packages. Please let me know how do that.

Comment: searching the web can help: http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/06/04/25840.html

Answer (score 2):

All source files can be found on CRAN:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/

You are looking for the tar.gz archive.

Answer (score 2):

You can also type the function you are interested in modifying's name into the R console without parentheses.  That will give you the code, but most even halfway complicated packages use either [S3](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/getS3method.html) or [S4](http://developer.r-project.org/howMethodsWork.pdf) classes/methods, so you'll need to know more about those to extend them properly.